# Duplicating record with unique id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I followed some solutions founded around and most of them was working but I'm having an issue of duplicating the SELECTED id record not only the structure of HTML.

```
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '<tr id="myrow">';
        echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['finishing'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['price'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td width=250>';
        echo '<a class="btn btn-warning" onclick=duplicate()>Duplicate</a>';    
    }
```

when i click the DUPLICATE button I want to duplicate the entire row with regard of the selected id.

That my duplicate implementation:

```
  var i = 1;
  $("table tr:first").clone().find("tr").each(function() {
     $(this).attr({
        'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
        'value': ''               
     });
  }).end().appendTo("table");

  i++;

  });
```

**UPDATE: Another Try for duplication:**

```
            document.getElementById('duplicateid').onclick = addMoreFields;
             var newRow = document.getElementById('myrow').cloneNode(true),
             myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
             function addMoreFields() {
                    myTable.appendChild(newRow.cloneNode(true));
                }
```

Comment: so, the code looks fine!! what else you want?

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to format your code readably.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao it is not working. Sorry T.J.

Comment: you have severe syntax errors in creating `anchor`. `onclick="duplicate()"` it should be..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the function `duplicate()` with quotation marks. `onclick="duplicate()"`

```
echo '<a class="btn btn-warning" onclick="duplicate()">Duplicate</a>';
```

**EDIT:**

Every row has the same ID (myrow), this is incorrect so Im going to change it to a class. Give each row a new attribute, like data-id.

Since Im sure the ID is a integer Im not giving it the attribute ID since ID's cant start with a integer.

```
echo '<tr class="myrow" data-id="'.$row['id'].'">';
```

and then send the ID to the duplicate function.

```
echo '<a class="btn btn-warning" onclick="duplicate(\''.$row['id'].'\')">Duplicate</a>';
```

And then duplicate the row and append it to the table.

```
    function duplicate(id){

     $("#themeTable tr[data-id='"+id+"']").clone().appendTo($("#themeTable"));

    }
```

I don't understand completly what you want. Is this it? Append the row to the end of the table on click?

Comment: I can call the function duplicate() no issues on that.

Comment: Might be, how can featuring each row with unique id?

Comment: Yes append the row to the end, i will try your answer and get back to you.

Comment: Make sense so far, this is my table declaration:     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="themeTable"> shall I use themeTable in place of     table or to keep it same? because it didn't work yet.

Comment: Updated my answer. Show more code next time you ask a question. It helps! :-) – Also, check your console for errors and see if the javascript is broken. For chrome, Developer Tools -> Console